# How can I determine the code coverage of my unit tests?

Tags: code-coverage, xdebug, phpunit, php-code-coverage

I am trying to determine the code-coverage of a group of unit tests. How can I do this?

I have phpUnit and XDebug installed on my machine and from what I understand these tools will do the job but I don't know how.

I've tried running

```
phpunit --coverage-html /unit_test/tester
```

I get back the PHPUnit version and the help list of potential commands, nothing to do with the code coverage.